# Python: Problem reading SQL results with pandas into list to be used in for loop

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

I am new to Python.

I have two SQL Views.

DBOP4 and DBOP4_SELECTION

DBOP4 contains many columns and many rows.
One column of DBOP4 is SaBeNummerDebitoren.

DBOP4_SELECTION:

```
SELECT        SaBeNummerDebitoren AS SBNr, [Sachbearbeiter Debitoren] AS SBName
FROM            dbo.DBOP4
GROUP BY SaBeNummerDebitoren, [Sachbearbeiter Debitoren]
```

I tried to write a python script, that outputs the results of DBOP4 seperated for each existing value in SaBeNummerDebitoren.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=***;'
                      'Database=***;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
 
SQL_SBNR_Selection = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT SBNR FROM DBOP4_SBSELECTION' ,conn)
print(SQL_SBNR_Selection)
#print(type(SQL_SBNR_Selection))

#Sachbearbeiternummer = ('1258','1278','1290')
Sachbearbeiternummer = pd.DataFrame(SQL_SBNR_Selection)

for sachbearbeiternr in Sachbearbeiternummer:
    print("Starte " + str(sachbearbeiternr))
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT *  FROM DBOP4 Where [SaBeNummerDebitoren] =' +str(sachbearbeiternr) ,conn)
    print(sql_query)
    print(type(sql_query))

    df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)

    df.to_excel (r'C:\OP\export_dataframe '+str(sachbearbeiternr)+'.xlsx', sheet_name='DBOP4_' +str(sachbearbeiternr) , index = False, header=True, freeze_panes=(1,5))
      

print("Fertig")
```

The output is a follows:

```
     SBNR
0  1258.0
1  1278.0
2  1290.0
Starte SBNR
```

Debugging Message:

```
Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT *  FROM DBOP4 Where [SaBeNummerDebitoren] =SBNR': ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Ungültiger Spaltenname 'SBNR'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
  File "C:\AzureDevopsRepos\Python Skripte\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 20, in <module>
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT *  FROM DBOP4 Where [SaBeNummerDebitoren] =' +str(sachbearbeiternr) ,conn)
```

Problems:
The for loop does not repeat the excel export for every number in my list ('1258','1278','1290').

When I did fill the Sachbearbeiternummer like this
`Sachbearbeiternummer = ('1258','1278','1290')`
The script worked.

**Problem 1:**
The loop starts with the name of the column SBNR instead of the first value.

**Problem 2:**
The loop does not continue after trying to use SBNR.
If I just do the `print("Starte " + str(sachbearbeiternr))` in the for loop, it also stops after SBNR.

I would be great if someone can help me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your for-loop (`for sachbearbeiternr in Sachbearbeiternummer`) iterates across columns of data frame which you then pass into query without quotes enclosing the literal value. That is why the error points to first column name, `SNBR`, as invalid name.

An immediate fix is to loop across specific column (or series) of data frame and then parameterize the query with value using *params* argument of [**`read_sql_query`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html). By the way, there is no need to call `DataFrame` after `read_sql_query` as docs indicate the return value of method is a `DataFrame`. Plus, you do not need a cursor for Pandas-SQL operations.

```
# ITERATE ACROSS COLUMN OR SERIES
for sachbearbeiternr in Sachbearbeiternummer['SBNR']:
    print("Starte " + str(sachbearbeiternr))
    ...
    # BIND ITERATOR VALUE AS PARAMETER
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM DBOP4 WHERE [SaBeNummerDebitoren] = ?',
                                  conn, params = [sachbearbeiternr])
```

With that said, there is no need for a second query or data frame. Simply import the *entire* view and then run Pandas' `groupby()` to split data frame by distinct values of `SaBeNummerDebitoren`. From there, iterate and process each subset.

```
df_DBOP4 = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT *  FROM DBOP4', conn)

# SPLIT DATA FRAME BY COLUMN: i IS SPLIT VALUE, g IS SUBSET DF
for i,g in df_DBOP4.groupby(['SaBeNummerDebitoren']):
    print("Starte " + str(i))        
    print(g.head(10))           # FIRST 10 ROWS

    df.to_excel(r'C:\OP\export_dataframe {0}.xlsx'.format(i), 
                sheet_name='DBOP4_'+str(i), index = False, 
                header=True, freeze_panes=(1,5))
```